# Как реализовать зарплату в Discord.py на Python?

Tags: python, discord.py

Например, каждый день на баланс пользователя поступает количество монет(в зависимости от профессии). Как это реализовать? Мне кажется это можно сделать с помощью декоратора @tasks.loop, но не знаю как.

Чтобы сделать вопрос ещё точнее - я пробовал с помощью @tasks.loop. С помощью asyncio.sleep() я ждал 30 секунд и на баланс действительно прибавились деньги. Только когда я делал с двумя аккаунтами тоже самое - бот сначала ждал 30 секунд у меня и начислял деньги, и только потом ждал 30 секунд для другого аккаунта. То есть в итоге для второго аккаунта ожидание денег составляло 60 секунд. Как сделать, чтобы зарплата начислялась за 30 секунд на всех аккаунтах?

Comment: а как у вас хранится список пользователей и текущий баланс ?

Comment: @Интик json, data['Граждане'][Тут айди пользователя]['Баланс']

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=task#discord-ext-tasks-asyncio-task-helpers

Comment: Я видел документацию. Я написал, что я знаю про этот декоратор, но я не понимаю как сделать зарплату с помощью него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаете сервер и перебираете всех пользователей, выдавая им деньги. Либо же вы можете полностью получить всех пользователей из json и выдать им деньги в зависимости от профессии через цикл for.

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=30.0)
async def pay(self):
    guild = # Тут нужно получить сервер с помощью айди или чего-то другого
    for m in guild.members:
        # Ваш код выдачи денег
```